# Constructing an Independent variable using two random variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove the following proposition

Given two random variables $X,Y$ (not necessarily iid), there exists a measurable function $f$ and random variable $N_{Y}$ such that $Y = f(X,N_Y)$ with $X$ and $N_Y$ independent.

My guess is that $f$ will have to do with the conditional CDF $F_{Y|X}$, but I'm not sure how to construct the noise variable $N_Y$. It seems like there should be an elegant answer to this but I couldn't find one. Is this a well known or obvious result? I'd appreciate any help with this!

EDIT: @geetha290krm pointed out correctly that this isn't possible in general. The question should also mention that the variables have a continuous support. (Perhaps the answer is still the same, I'm not sure).

Answer (score 1):

This is not always possible. There exists a probability  measure $P$ on $\mathbb N$ (with the power set) such if $U$ and $V$ are independent r.v.'s on it then one of them at least has to be a constant . (In fact, you can construct even simpler examples of this  using a finite sample space).  In that case either $N_Y$ is a constant (if $X$ is not). But the $Y$ is necessarily a measurable function of $X$ which can fail.

Comment: Interesting. Would this be true if we forced the variables to have continuous support? Those are the main kinds of variables I'm interested in. I've made an edit to the original question to reflect this - to clarify for others